# Ambiguous error message when the page loads

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm learning Blazor and a simple Blazor reg form is giving me the blues.  Below is the html, code and the error message.  One odd thing that's happening is that the `Submitted` method is executed when the page loads without the submit button of the form being clicked.  Then the page errors out with the error below in inspect.  What am I doing wrong please?  Thanks in advance.

[image: Error Message]

[image: Form]

```
@code {

public Register()
{

}

public RegisterDto rdto { get; set; } = new RegisterDto();

public async Task Submitted()
{

    HttpResponseMessage hrm = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<RegisterDto>
("https://localhost:44368/api/Account/Register", rdto);

    if (hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string ss = await hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean giving you the blues ? I only see reds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What am I doing wrong?"

- Not reading the error message carefully
- binding to "value" instead of "Value"

Blazor is a case sensitive language - you should bind to the "Value" parameter, not "value"

```html
<InputText @bind-Value="@rdto.City"/>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, that was it.  With my ADD, Blazor and I will have tons of `fun`